# Spring Security-encrypted string - decryption in Go fails

Tags: java, spring, go, encryption, spring-security

The encryption will be done on the client-side with the following Spring Security-Encryptors based code:

```java
package at.wrwks.pipe.baumgmt.component.documentpreview;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SecureResourceUrlComposer {
    public String compose(final String resource) {
        final var salt = new String(Hex.encode("salt".getBytes(UTF_8)));
        final var encryptor = Encryptors.stronger("password", salt);
        final var encryptedResource = encryptor.encrypt(resource.getBytes(UTF_8));
        final var base64EncodedEncryptedResource = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedResource);
        final var urlEncodedBase64EncodedEncryptedResource = URLEncoder.encode(base64EncodedEncryptedResource, UTF_8);
        return "https://target" + "?resource=" + urlEncodedBase64EncodedEncryptedResource;
    }
}
```

Sample resource: `aResource`

URL- and base64-encoded output: `https://target?resource=yEAdq1toEfbcTKcAeTJmw7zLYdk4fA2waASPzSfqQxAxiq7bmUarUYE%3D`

The decryption fails with `cipher: message authentication failed` in the following backend code written in Go at `gcm.Open`:

```
func decryptGcmAes32(ciphertext, key string) (plaintext string, err error) {
    if len(key) != 32 {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected key length (!= 32) '%s' %d", key, len(key))
        err = errors.New(msg)
        log.Warn(err)
        sentry.CaptureException(err)
        return
    }
    keyBytes := []byte(key)
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(keyBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("Couldn't create a cipher block", err)
        sentry.CaptureException(err)
        return
    }

    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("Couldn't wrap in gcm mode", err)
        sentry.CaptureException(err)
        return
    }

    nonceSize := gcm.NonceSize()
    if len(ciphertext) < nonceSize {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("Ciphertext shorter than nonce size %d < %d", len(ciphertext), nonceSize)
        err = errors.New(msg)
        log.Warn(err)
        sentry.CaptureException(err)
        return
    }
    ciphertextBytes := []byte(ciphertext)
    nonce, ciphertextBytes := ciphertextBytes[:nonceSize], ciphertextBytes[nonceSize:]
    plaintextBytes, err := gcm.Open(nil, nonce, ciphertextBytes, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("Couldn't decode", err)
        sentry.CaptureException(err)
        return
    }
    plaintext = string(plaintextBytes)
    return
}
```

The following test in `go` works *only* if the `iv` is the same for both the encryption and the decryption

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2"
    "log"
    "testing"
)
var iv = make([]byte, 12)

func TestCrypto(t *testing.T) {
    rand.Read(iv)
    encrypted, _ := encrypt("aResource")
    if decrypted, err := decrypt(encrypted); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Printf("DECRYPTED: %s\n", decrypted)
    }

}

func encrypt(secret string) (result []byte, err error) {
    salt := []byte("salt")
    key := pbkdf2.Key([]byte("b0226e4e9bef40d4b8aed039c208ae3e"), salt, 1024, 16, sha1.New)
    b, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(b)
    result = aesgcm.Seal(nil, iv, []byte(secret), nil)
    return
}

func decrypt(ciphertext []byte) (result string, err error) {
    salt := []byte("salt")
    key := pbkdf2.Key([]byte("b0226e4e9bef40d4b8aed039c208ae3e"), salt, 1024, 16, sha1.New)
    b, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(b)
    decrypted, err := aesgcm.Open(ciphertext[:0], iv, ciphertext, nil)
    result = string(decrypted)
    return
}
```

Comment: Your Go code looks correct so far, but it is incomplete. You should add the code for the key derivation to the question and make sure you didn't forget to base64-decode (I find it *very* odd that you pass the ciphertext and key as strings; the base64 package and pretty much any PBKDF2 package return byte slices and there is no reason to ever treat them as text since they are, for all intents and purposes, random data). A sample plain/ciphertext pair would be helpful too.

Comment: @Peter The URL- and Base64-decoding happens in a previous step which has been omitted. I added a sample plain/ciphertext pair.

Comment: The error message indicates that either key or IV are incorrect. The key derivation step is an integral part and we can't help you without seeing that code.

Comment: @Peter On the client side it will be done by Spring. On the server side this is everything I've got. Do you mean the use of ```pbkdf2.Key()```? If not, could you please add an answer and describe how you would implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the major points:

- In order the apply the salt and derive a proper key `pbkdf2.Key()` must be used as shown below
- the `nonce` (or `Initialization Vector`) size in Spring Security is 16 bytes as opposed to the 12 bytes in `go`

The excerpt below omits error handling just to emphasise the essence of the solution:

```golang
const nonceSize = 16
func decryptWithAes256GcmPbkdf2(cipherBytes []byte, password string, salt string) (string) {
    key := pbkdf2.Key([]byte(password), []byte(salt), 1024, 32, sha1.New)
    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
    gcm, _ := cipher.NewGCMWithNonceSize(c, nonceSize)
    plaintextBytes, _ := gcm.Open(nil, cipherBytes[:nonceSize], cipherBytes[nonceSize:], nil)
    return string(plaintextBytes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the question relates to the "stronger" decryption.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/Encryptors.html

I would like to give a full example to the "standard" decryption to extend the previous answer.

In my case the task was to implement the following Java code in Go:

```
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor;
    ...
    private static final String SALT = "123456789abcdef0"; // hex
    public static String decrypt(final String encryptedText, final String password) {
        TextEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.text(password, SALT);
        return encryptor.decrypt(encryptedText);
    }
```

The code translated to Go:

```
import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2"
)

func decryptWithAes256CbcPbkdf2(cipherBytes []byte, passwordBytes []byte, saltBytes []byte) string {
    key := pbkdf2.Key(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1024, 32, sha1.New)
    if len(key) != 32 {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected key length (!= 32) '%s' %d", key, len(key)))
    }

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if len(cipherBytes) < aes.BlockSize {
        panic("ciphertext too short")
    }
    iv := cipherBytes[:aes.BlockSize]
    cipherBytes = cipherBytes[aes.BlockSize:]
    if len(cipherBytes)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("ciphertext is not a multiple of the block size")
    }
    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(cipherBytes, cipherBytes)
    return strings.Trim(string(cipherBytes), "\b")
}

func main() {
    cipherText := "05589d13fe6eedceae78fe099eed2f6b238ac7d4dbb62c281ccdc9401b24bb0c"
    cipherBytes, _ := hex.DecodeString(cipherText)
    passwordText := "12345"
    passwordBytes := []byte(passwordText)
    saltText := "123456789abcdef0"
    saltBytes, _ := hex.DecodeString(saltText)
    plainText := decryptWithAes256CbcPbkdf2(cipherBytes, passwordBytes, saltBytes)
    fmt.Println(plainText)
}
```